# Is there ActiveX support for Webview2 control

Tags: activex, webview2

The new webview2 control is based on the latest edge, chrome based. In Edge there is an IE mode to support the actvive x. Do we have option to use the IE mode in webview2 control so that we can webview2 control support activeX

Comment: WebView2 use Edge Chromium, not the original Edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView2 does not support Edge's [IE Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) and also otherwise has no way to use ActiveX within WebView2. If you'd like to make a feature request you can do so on the [WebView2 Feedback repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues).

Unfortunately unlike most Edge features, IE Mode in particular is a lot of additional work to turn on in WebView2. Since IE Mode swaps out the underlying web platform engine we would have to do work for every WebView2 feature to work properly in IE Mode.

Comment: How about the possibility to have it as an activex control, regardless of doing ie_mode-fu?

Comment: Do you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68740038/is-it-possible-to-use-webview2-in-activex ? It should be possible to create an ActiveX control wrapper around WebView2. It is not provided directly by the WebView2 team and offhand I don't know of any third party WebView2 ActiveX control wrappers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I saw some attempt at it on this repo: https://github.com/sysdzw/WebView2DemoForVb6 but I'm yet to try to trust this `RC6.dll`