# Is it possible to use WebView2 in Activex?

Tags: activex, webview2

Can we use WebView2 inside an instance of Activex?
Is there any embodiment that I can consult while I develop mine?
We want to avoid the possible costs in the company in advance otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to use WebView2 in ActiveX, but it is not directly supported.

The WebView2 nuget package includes a COM interface based API, but it does not implement ActiveX support. It should be possible to implement an ActiveX control on top of this, but I don't know of any public implementation. Searching on github for WebView2 and ActiveX I do see one project that may be helpful but I have no knowledge on it.

Comment: I saw some attempt at it on this repo: https://github.com/sysdzw/WebView2DemoForVb6 but I'm yet to try to trust this `RC6.dll`, or find its source somewhere.